# Signature of quadratic form when q(x)=l1(x)*l2(x)

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $l1: R^n -> R$ , $l2:R^n -> R$ be linear transformations.
We assume $n\ge2$, $l1\not=0$ and $l2\not=0$.
Let's define quadratic form $q: R^n -> R$ such that $q(x)=l1(x)*l2(x)$ for every $x\in R^n$.

1. Prove there is a subspace of dimension $n-1$ of $R^n$ on which $q=0$.
2. Prove that the signature of $q$ is either $0, 1$ or $-1$.

So for the first part I know that since $n = dimIml1 + dimKerl1$ then $dimKerl1 = n-1$ (since $Iml1$ is not zero, otherwise $l1=0$).
So there is a subspace $V$ of dimension $n-1$ such that $l1=0$. I can use the same subspace to show that $q(x)=l1(x)*l2(x) =0$ for every $x\in\ V$.

2. This where things gets complicated for me. I tried to use the associated bilinear form $f(u,v)=(1/2)*(q(u+v)-q(u)-q(v)) $ to prove the rank of the representing matrix of $q$ is at most 1 (hence in the diagonal form there is at most one term, whose coefficient can be either 0, positive or negative so the signature is 0, 1, -1 accordingly)

But I get a matrix of the following nature:
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & ... &0& a_1 \\
    0   & 0 &... &0&   a_2 \\
    .     &.&.  &.& .\\
    .&.&.&.&.\\
    0 &  0 & ... & 0&a_{n-1} \\
    a_1 & a_2 & ... & a_{n-1} & a_n \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

And I know that $a_n\not=0$.
What can I do next?

Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: How many non-zero rows (columns) does that last matrix have? ...

Comment: I can't know for sure. that depends on $a_i$, which I can't determine because I don't know $l2(v_i)$ (If I consider the basis on $R^n$ that was complemented from the basis of part 1 of the question).

Comment: Hint: $q(x)=x^\top l_1^\top l_2x$.

Comment: @Chrystomath I'm having trouble understand why, shouldn't it be ( $l_1xl_2x$)? that's ($(x^Tl_1^T)^Tl_2x$, no?)

Comment: Oh, I think I get it, since $(x^Tl_1^T)^T$ is a scalar then $(x^Tl_1^T)^T=(x^Tl_1^T)$?

Comment: Actually, I should have written $x^\top l_1l_2^\top x$ if the vectors $l_i$ are columns. But yes, they're scalars; also the matrix in question is $l_1l_2^\top$.

Comment: semi duplicate of this posting from today as well:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3872071/rank-of-a-quadratic-form-q-mathbbf-n-rightarrow-mathbbf-where-there ... Note: for this question if the bilinear form isn't supposed to be symmetric(/Hermitian) how is the signature defined?  (It can't be defined via congruence.)  Alternatively if we are dealing with a symmetric bilinear form then we may have rank 2-- i.e. part 2 of this exercise is wrong.