# rank of a quadratic form $q : \mathbb{F} ^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ where there is a subspace of dimension $n-1$ that the form returns $0$ above?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, matrix-rank

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field such that $char(\mathbb{F}) \not= 2$ . 
Let $q : \mathbb{F} ^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ $(n \geq 2)$ be a quadratic form - defined such that there are $n-1$ linearly independent vectors $v _1 , \dots , v _{n-1}$  for which - 
$\forall v \in Sp(\{v _1 , \dots , v _{n-1}\}) : q(v) = 0$ .

Can we say anything about the rank of $q$? 
If not over a general field, does the answer change above $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

**NOTE:** 
The question has meaning, because we CAN always define such $q$ :

let $l _1 , l _2$ be non-zero linear transformations from $\mathbb{F} ^n$ to $\mathbb{F}$ .

Let us define $q: v \mapsto l _1(v) l _2(v)$ . $^{(***) }$ $^{see}$ $^{comment}$ $^{bellow.}$ 
We will demonstrate such a subspace of dimention $n-1$ that $q$ "sends" to $0$ .

$dim(Im(l _1)) = dim( \mathbb{F}) = 1$ . 
we also know that:   $dim(Ker(l _1)) + dim(Im(l _1)) = dim(\mathbb{F} ^n) = n$ 
So, we get  $dim(Ker(l _1)) = n-1$ .

Indeed, $\forall v \in Ker(l _1) : q(v) = l_1(v)l_2(v) = 0l_2(v) = 0$ , and we are done.

---

$^{***}$ - $q$ indeed is a quadratic form over $\mathbb{F} ^n$ . it is fairly easy to show that if $f : \mathbb{F} ^n \times \mathbb{F} ^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ is defined as $f(u,w) = l _1(u )l _2 ( w )$ for all $u,w \in \mathbb{F} ^n$, then $f$ is a bilinear form over $\mathbb{F} ^n$, and $f(v,v) = q(v)$ for all $v \in \mathbb{F} ^n$.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\Bbb F$ is not of characteristic $2$, the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) yields the associated symmetric bilinear form
$$
b(v,u) = \frac 12 (q(u,v) - q(u) - q(v)).
$$
Thus, $q$ can be associated with a symmetric matrix $A \in \Bbb F^{n \times n}$ (such that $q(v) = v^TAv$).

Complete the set $\{v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\}$ to form a basis $\mathcal B = \{v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},v_n\}$. From the information given, we know that the matrix associated with this quadratic form has the form
$$
A = \pmatrix{0_{(n-1) \times (n-1)} & x\\ x^T & \alpha},
$$
where $x \in \Bbb F^{n-1}$ and $\alpha \in \Bbb F$. It is easy to see that there are three possibilities for rank of this matrix (and therefore the rank of the quadratic form): it must either be $0$, $1$ (which holds iff $x = 0$), or $2$.

In fact, based on the form of the matrix, we can say that for some $v_1,v_2 \in \Bbb F^n$, the quadratic form must be
$$
q(x) = x^T[v_1v_2^T + v_2^Tv_1] x = 2(v_1^Tx)(v_2^Tx).
$$

Comment: At my attempt at the problem, I too got that the representing matrix should look the way you stated. How from there do you get ONLY $1$ or $2$ for possible non-zero rank values?

Comment: Each column except the last is a multiple of $(0,\dots,0,1)$. So, the span of the columns has dimension at most $2$.